# installing intl entension on php5.4.4

Tags: php-extension, php-5.4, intl

I am trying to install intl extension on php 5.4.4 having centos,

I have a zip file which I downloaded from http://isolherbal.com/nha/playground_clone/webservices/test_webservices

I downloaded version 3.0.0

But from here I do not know where to go because the file does not containes intl.so and I dint find any way to compile and cretae an so from the directory present in the zip

Comment: Which releae (version) of CentOS do you use? Exactly how (and from which repository) did yo install that php version?

Comment: centos is 5.1 and for installing php I used linux command "yum"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue, It was because icu was not installed on my server, intl extension has dependency over icu and autoconf so my server was missing icu extension I configured that first and then intl go

for more help refer http://dreamconception.com/tech/install-intl-extension-with-mamp/